# htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work properly if no trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect one subdirectory to another using RewriteRule in the main directory's .htaccess file.

For example: http://website.com/subdir should rewrite to http://website.com/another_dir/destination_dir but the user should still see http://website.com/subdir in the address bar.

This works perfectly if the user ends the URL with a trailing slash.  Example: http://website.com/subdir/  (Generates a 200

However, if the slash is omitted, a 301 redirect is generated and we see the undesired destination directory. For example, http://website/subdir redirects the user to http://website/another_dir/destination_dir

Here are the pertinent parts of .htaccess:

```
# URL Rewriting:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

...

# Redirect subdirectories:
RewriteRule ^subdir(.*)$ another_dir/destination_dir$1 [PT,NC,QSA,L]
```

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the regex in your rewrite rule to optionally match a slash.

```
RewriteRule ^subdir(/?.*)$ another_dir/destination_dir$1 [PT,NC,QSA,L]
```

Note the `/?` just after `subdir`. This says that there may or may not be a slash just after your subdir, so the regex will match either way.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be

`DirectorySlash OFF` in this htaccess, and `DirectorySlash ON` a .htaccess in another_dir/